# Why the default tint color of UITableViewCell differ?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In some case it's white
[image]

In other cases, it's blue

[image]

Both are default. I noticed that one I change recently and the other have always been default. The blue ones are the one that have always been default.

Perhaps something changes when I upgrade the project to Xcode 5?

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know why. Just go at file inspector. Select open with Xcode 5. Once seen with the new format, the tint will go to the new default which is blue.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, cells have a white background by default, you can change it in coading.

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
```